# Required order of columns names which does not have NULL values

Tags: r, data.table

My data is bit typical and I need find out field/Column order that follow some pattern.

For Instance, One field(say sub3) has values till some rows and followed by NULL values, then another field will continue with some values(like Sub1) and then follows null values.

And in some cases I may have multiple fields having values at two rows(like Sub2 and Sub4).

In below case the solution is vector of field names which follow the pattern `c(Sub3,Sub1,c(Sub2,Sub4),Sub5)`

Here is the reproducible format of data and Snapshot of data.

```
structure(list(RollNo = 1:10, Sub1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 2L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), Sub2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", "B", NA, 
    NA), Sub3 = c(4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Sub4 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 5L, NA, NA), Sub5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 7L, NA)), .Names = c("RollNo", "Sub1", "Sub2", 
    "Sub3", "Sub4", "Sub5"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", 
    "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000200788>)
```

[image: SnapShot of the data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using:

```
DT[, nms := paste0(names(.SD)[!is.na(.SD)], collapse = ','), 1:nrow(DT), .SDcols = 2:6]
```

will get you:

```
> DT
    RollNo Sub1 Sub2 Sub3 Sub4 Sub5       nms
 1:      1   NA   NA    4   NA   NA      Sub3
 2:      2   NA   NA    3   NA   NA      Sub3
 3:      3   NA   NA    5   NA   NA      Sub3
 4:      4   NA   NA    6   NA   NA      Sub3
 5:      5    3   NA   NA   NA   NA      Sub1
 6:      6    2   NA   NA   NA   NA      Sub1
 7:      7   NA    A   NA    2   NA Sub2,Sub4
 8:      8   NA    B   NA    5   NA Sub2,Sub4
 9:      9   NA   NA   NA   NA    7      Sub5
10:     10   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

If you just want the specified vector:

```
unique(DT[, paste0(names(.SD)[!is.na(.SD)], collapse = ','), 1:nrow(DT), .SDcols = 2:6][V1!='']$V1)
```

which returns:

```
[1] "Sub3"      "Sub1"      "Sub2,Sub4" "Sub5"
```

As @Frank pinted out in the comments, you can also use:

```
melt(DT, id=1, na.rm = TRUE)[, toString(unique(variable)), by = RollNo][order(RollNo)]
```

Comment: To avoid the evils of 1:nrow, matrix coercion, etc, maybe `melt(DT, id="RollNo", na.rm = TRUE)[, toString(unique(variable)), by=RollNo]` and then update-join on that.

Comment: @jaap Can you please explain what 1:nrow(DT) is doing?

Comment: @PPC `1:nrow(DT)` ensures that the comparison is done by row

Comment: @japp do you have any idea on how to access element from a list, I want to access 1st element of "Sub2,Sub4" . I can split by ',' and do it. But there should be some correct way.

Comment: @PPC will look at it later today (tonight), but my first guess would to use `as.list` instead of `toString` and then use list subsetting; another option would to use `gsub` and capture everything before the first comma

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are sorting on the order of first non-`NA` data. If `df` is your data:

```
sapply(df, function(x) min(Inf, head(which(!is.na(x)),n=1)))
# RollNo   Sub1   Sub2   Sub3   Sub4   Sub5 
#      1      5      7      1      7      9
```

Gives the first non-`NA` row for each column. This should be a natural sort, meaning ties retain the original order between the ties.

There are a couple of ways to use this, one such:

```
order(sapply(df, function(x) min(Inf, head(which(!is.na(x)),n=1))))
# [1] 1 4 2 3 5 6
df[,order(sapply(df, function(x) min(Inf, head(which(!is.na(x)),n=1))))]
#    RollNo Sub3 Sub1 Sub2 Sub4 Sub5
# 1       1    4   NA <NA>   NA   NA
# 2       2    3   NA <NA>   NA   NA
# 3       3    5   NA <NA>   NA   NA
# 4       4    6   NA <NA>   NA   NA
# 5       5   NA    3 <NA>   NA   NA
# 6       6   NA    2 <NA>   NA   NA
# 7       7   NA   NA    A    2   NA
# 8       8   NA   NA    B    5   NA
# 9       9   NA   NA <NA>   NA    7
# 10     10   NA   NA <NA>   NA   NA
```

I'm inferring from the column names that `RollNo` should always be first, so:

```
df[,c(1, 1 + order(sapply(df[-1], function(x) min(Inf, head(which(!is.na(x)),n=1)))))]
```